# Deleting records in MongoDB than no longer have a valid URL

Tags: mongodb

I'm scraping content from web pages into MongoDB. One of the fields I'm capturing is the URL of the page. In order to keep my database up to date, I'd like to completely delete the record of any page where the URL returns a 404 error. Looking through the documentation, it seems like I'm going to need to write a script (preferably in Python) that combines `http.post()` and `db.collection.remove()`.

Before attempting to write it, I wanted to check to see if I was thinking about this correctly or if anyone had suggestions about the best way to approach the problem.

Comment: I don't think using MongoDB's `http.post()` is a good idea. First of all `http.post()` will make a `POST` request, however to check page availability you need to make a `GET` request. There is an `http.get()` request for that. But if you are aiming to use Python it might be much easier to use some Python library like [requests](https://github.com/psf/requests) for making requests and any driver for MongoDB for data manipulations.

Comment: Great suggestions. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone with a similar issue comes across this looking for a solution, here's a simple script that worked for me:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import requests

client = MongoClient("mongodb+srv://USERNAME:PASSWORD@cluster0-hotkd.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
db = client["Cluster0-sandbox"]
col = db['openings']
openings = list(col.find())

for item in openings:
    if requests.get(item['Link']).status_code != 200:
        db.openings.remove(item)
```